# Should I use a pipe or dash in window title?

Tags: gui-design

When an application window title needs to show a subtitle, I've seen 2 ways: Pipes and Dashes:

Pipe:

[image: Pipe]

Dash:

[image: Dash]

Although most I've seen recently are dashes (the Google Sheets example was played around in HTML).

What is better from a UX point of view?

Comment: Mostly opinion-based, and doesn't seem likely to make much difference since functionally there isn't one ... Only thought is that tabs & buttons on iOS & Android now often just appear as text, perhaps separated by "|", so the latter "pipe" option kind of looks like it could be separate tabs or links. The dash doesn't give that impression. But if it doesn't do anything, there's little chance of confusion. Does anyone really look at the window title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Depends on what you want to convey.**

I'd interpret the line with the dash as a full page name or a sentence where the two are not seperable.

I'd interpret the pipe as though you're trying to convey two seperate statements, possibly two levels of navigation.

So I'm going to turn the question around on you; which seems more fitting?

*(the reason I return a question as an answer, is that it looks like the "title" you refer to, is a single word. If that's the case everywhere, the pipe might be better!)*

Comment: My use case is an application title with the current signed in user both on the title bar, sort of "Application Title | John Doe"

Comment: Your logic seems correct, so I guess I should use pipes.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, Vertical pipes are mainly used to visually separate elements.So, in your case, if Subheader you want to give more emphasis then you can use "|" or else you can go ahead with "-". Hope my answer is helpful to you